# Should I search on Internet before asking question?

Tags: discussion

The site is in beta version. I am seeing many users asking a question whose answer is easily available on first result of google search.

On the otherhand other site of SE like Stackoverflow, it has rule that before asking any question a user should search enough, show some effort code & error if any. All this information considered as proper question.

Should this type of same scenario apply on Hinduism site too ?

Comment: In Beta, NO. We need to gain attraction. So, ask good questions (_if you know the answer, answer it yourself_).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Everything is searchable, unless someone questioned it previously, answers on Stackexchange network matters because they are answered by professionals and accepted by community.

The site is in Beta and we are building a solid database of good questions and answers, not the general or basic ones.

Users can find information at various personal blogs or sites but what matters is authenticity of the content they share on their sites as there is no one to review their content. I will provide you one example for this :

[Was Lord Rama a non-vegetarian?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2002/was-lord-rama-a-non-vegetarian)

Now in the above question, the site which is referenced by the user who asked the question translated wrongly, and hence, provides false information to his visitors, whereas on Stackexchange, we have other users to review the answers by upvoting the good ones, and down voting the wrong ones which helps other users to refer a genuine answer.

Not only that, some users also provide secondary solution/version answer, which is useful as not all websites cover different versions of answers, so....

**Should I search on Internet before asking question?** - Yes, do it if your query is basic or it is too broad, or you have skeptical questions like whether this is true or not etc types.

But if your question is interesting, unanswered by search, you think may be helpful to others if I post it here, than ask, nothings wrong in asking a question which is searchable online, so that users get authentic information from this site.

Comment: Mr. Downvoter should also mentioned reason for downvoting. However I am not the downvoter neither I am agree with your answer.

Comment: @Kedarnath than are you expecting that we shouldn't ask question which are searchable? than if thats the thing, only 20 questions will stay on this site... rest we can delete because all of them are searchable, and thats the reason every answer has a reference, what matters is the content we share here

Comment: "_but what matters is authenticity of the content they share_" And how exactly do you verify the content of _this_ site?

Comment: @AwalGarg I think you didn't read the answer which states **we have other users to review the answers by upvoting the good ones, and down voting the wrong ones which helps other users to refer a genuine answer**

Comment: @Mr.Alien I think you didn't read the comment. Can't all the users be wrong?

Comment: @AwalGarg I don't think ALL can go wrong

Comment: @Mr.Alien if a mod can go wrong like this on meta, I can hardly imagine such a situation to be rare.

Comment: @AwalGarg Mods are not gods :) also meta is all about opinions..

Answer (score 2):

This site is in Beta stage and it needs contributors. So, as a responsible user we should contribute to this site by researching (*if possible*) and posting some good questions which could make up to the Hot Network Questions (HNQ).

So, in Beta stage, we should try to ask good questions even though they are easily searchable on Intenet.